# How can I enable syntax highlighting for .vue files in Atom?

Tags: vue.js, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I'm starting up with Vue.js.  The first problem I've run into is that my IDE (Atom) doesn't beautify my .vue files.  It's all just white text.

How can I make Atom highlight .vue files properly?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[language-vue](https://atom.io/packages/language-vue) package adds syntax highlighting to Vue components.

There is also another package to beautify your code. Install [atom-beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) package. It has `Vue beautifier` preinstalled.

Comment: language-vue did the job for me, very beautiful. thanks! [+1]

Answer (score 11):

The [Vue.js project](https://github.com/vuejs) maintains [Awesome Vue.js](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue), "a curated list of awesome things related to Vue.js".

This includes [a list of useful Atom packages for Vue.js](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#source-code-editing):

> - [language-vue@atom.io](https://github.com/hedefalk/atom-vue) - Vue component file syntax for Atom.
> - [language-vue-component@atom.io](https://github.com/CYBAI/language-vue-component) - Adds syntax highlighting to Vue Component files in Atom.
> - [vue-autocomplete@atom.io](https://github.com/ealves-pt/atom-vue-autocomplete) - Vue.js 1.0+ autocomplete for Atom.
> - [vue-snippets@atom.io](https://github.com/ealves-pt/atom-vue-snippets) - Atom snippets for Vue component files.
> - [vue-autocompile@atom.io](https://github.com/paulpflug/vue-autocompile) - Auto compile vue file on save.
> - [lint-sass-vue@atom.io](https://github.com/fsblemos/lint-sass-vue) - Atom.io package to lint Sass/SCSS in `.vue` files.
> - [vuejs2-snippets@atom.io](https://github.com/CorentinAndre/Vuejs-snippets) - Atom snippets for javascript and components, including lifecycle hooks, directives, properties, vuex, vue-router, vue-i18n support.
> - [vue2-autocomplete@atom.io](https://github.com/ealves-pt/atom-vue2-autocomplete) - Vue.js 2.0+ autocomplete for Atom.

Note that currently the `language-vue` and `language-vue-component` do not play nicely together, [as discussed here](https://github.com/CYBAI/language-vue-component/issues/20). For now, for syntax highlighting in Atom your best bet is `language-vue` only.

Comment: Quit a few of these are supplaced with vui-cli (of vue ui) that already have automatic compiling and webpack-ing. I can recommend language-vue

Answer (score 1):

Use in your command prompt:

```
apm install language-vue
```

for syntax highlighting.

There is another Atom package which seems to only beautify it but doesn't do syntax highlighting:

```
apm install vue-format
```

You may need to exit Atom and then restart it.