# My editor doesn't recognize a component with extension .vue "ChatApp.vue" in a laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, atom-editor

My editor doesn't recognize a  component with extension .vue "ChatApp.vue" in a laravel project. Im using atom by the way.
All code is in grey instead of colored as the editor does with other parts and files of the laravel project.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I enable syntax highlighting for .vue files in Atom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45227611/how-can-i-enable-syntax-highlighting-for-vue-files-in-atom)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a syntax highlighter. Install either of these packages.
https://atom.io/packages/language-vue package to enable syntax highlighting to Vue components.
https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify package. This will help in highlighting as well as indenting.